# Convert Query String to Array

Tags: php, jquery

How can I convert this to an array in PHP?

```
&height=0&weight=2&width=10
```

I'm passing a data from a jquery function using `.serialize()` to a PHP function.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @Akam: He's asking how to do it unserialize that string into an array in PHP

Comment: yes, then see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: If you're using `serialize()` properly, it would already be an array in either `$_POST` or `$_GET` on the serverside, depending on the method you're using.

Comment: It is already an array. `print_r($_GET)`, `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: thank you ..now i was able to convert it but im having a problem on how to access it.

Comment: i did this  parse_str($_POST,$dataArray) but i cannot access it by doing this $dataArray[height]. am i missing something?

Comment: `$_POST` is already an array!

Comment: **dont** use parse_str. The other answeerer didn't think about your question hard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what type of request you are performing, it may already be in an array. Have a look at the PHP documentation on [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) global variables.

To view the contents of said array. You can use the function [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) which will show you the contents of the array.

`print_r($_GET)`

`print_r($_POST)`

Access individual items in the array by the item's key. For example:

`echo $_POST['height'];`

Comment: As i understand the question, this is the answer

Comment: @roasted I understood the question as you did.

Comment: thanks! it is already an array..hehe

Answer (score 5):

Can be done within one line. :)

```
parse_str('&height=0&weight=2&width=10', $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I don't know why down voted, I just up-voted against it :)

Comment: Yup that is correct  +1

Comment: One-liner only if you don't have _strict error reporting_! :] If you have, you'll have to declare `$array = array()` first or you get stuck with undeclared variable notice. And one-liner dream is gone! :]